# iOS 8 Swift 1.2 and Parse - Attempt to present UIAlertController on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, ios8

There are many questions on Stack concerning this issue, but none of them seem to solve the issue I'm having.

I am using ParseUI for the login and signup portion of my application.  What I would *like* to have happen is for a `UIAlertController` to be presented when a user (for example) does not enter in any text in the username and password fields.

Here is the code for my `MasterViewController`:

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate,
PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
            var logInViewController = LoginViewController()
            logInViewController.delegate = self

            var signUpViewController = SignUpViewController()
            signUpViewController.delegate = self

            logInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

            self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController,
        shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

            if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
                return true
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to login.",
                    message: "Login Failure.  Please try again.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


                return false
            }
    }



    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController,
        didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError?) {

            println("Failed to log in.")

    }


    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController,
        shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

            if let password = info["password"] as? String {
                return count(password.utf16) >= 8
            } else {
                return false
            }
    }

    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController,
        didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError?) {

            println("Failed to sign up.")

    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController,
        didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
            let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            installation.saveInBackground()
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController:
        PFSignUpViewController) {

            println("User dismissed signup.")

    }
}
```

After reading another user's answer which seemed like it would be the answer, I added the following class to my workspace:

```
import Foundation

class AlertHelper: NSObject {
    func showAlert(fromController controller: MasterViewController) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "abc", message: "def", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And then modified my method accordingly:

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController,
    shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

```
    if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
        return true
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to login.",
            message: "Login Failure.  Please try again.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        var alert = AlertHelper()
        alert.showAlert(fromController: self)

        return false
    }
```

}

At this point I'm not quite sure what else to do.  One thought I had was to programmatically add a `UILabel` to my `LoginViewController` and `SignUpViewController` and change the content based on the errors (or lack thereof) for the user login and signup, but I would like to have alerts.

EDIT:  This is the code in my `LoginViewController`.  It subclassed in order to customize the appearance.  The code for my `SignUpViewController` is almost identical.

import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

```
class LoginViewController: PFLogInViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = ckPurple

    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.text = "Welcome."
    label.sizeToFit()
    logInView?.logo = label

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you present a login view controller from your master view controller, which removes the master view controller from the view hierarchy. You then attempt to present an alert view controller from your master view controller, but you need to present from a view controller in the view hierarchy. Try presenting the alert *from your login view controller* instead.

```
loginController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Your answer was quite close.  Instead it was `loginController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)` (and in the case of sign up, it was `signUpController` because I had to reference the `PFLoginViewController` and PFSignupViewController` in the delegate methods.

Comment: OK I changed `loginViewController` to `loginController`. Glad my answer was helpful to you, please consider marking it correct.